# How can I get the timestamp in “yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff"” format in VBA?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, datetime, date-formatting

I want to get this output:

```
2018-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

I tried the below code:

```vb
.Cells(LRS + 1, 15).Value = Format(.Cells(LRS + 1, "A").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

And I got:

```
2018-09-02 00:00:00.fff
```

The initial date in Excel has the following format `yyyy/mm/dd`, no time included. That's why the time part includes only zeros `00:00:00.000`. The reason I want to include the time in the specific format is that I'm planning to import those dates into a SQL table with that format.

Is there any solution?

Comment: As you can see from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications `fff` is not recognised as a formatting token. Does the original data you're processing even contain this info anyway? I mention it because the default `datetime` in older MySQL doesn't include milliseconds or microseconds - you'd have to use datetime(3) or datetime(6) instead.

Comment: The initial date has the following format "yyyy/mm/dd", no time included, that s why time part includes only zeros 00:00:00.000. The reason i want to include the time in the specific format is that in planning to import those dates in sql table with that format.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.000` is the right format to display time in Excel with milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) `fff` is not recognised as a formatting token in VBA.

Helpfully, you can actually import your data into SQL without formatting it to add the time. If you import it into a `datetime` field the SQL engine will automatically default the time part of the field to midnight on the date you give it.

I think you can just change your format string to `yyyy-MM-dd` by itself.

However if you really want to do it like this, then since there's no time specified then just hard-code `000` instead of `fff`. The rest of the time can be similarly hard-coded, since it never varies, so you end up with `yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000`. But as I said, I think it's a bit pointless.

Comment: i will use this simple format string yyyy-MM-dd and hard code the time because nothing else works.

Comment: To be clear, you don't need to do anything with the time at all. You can leave it out. I would be very surprised if that didn't work - mySQL should accept a simple date in an import to a datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the cell format with the corresponding format, it is likely that the value of the cell is imported as text, not as a value.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, s1 As String, s2 As String
    'First Cell format as your "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000"
    Range("a2").NumberFormatLocal = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000"

    'In vb,This format("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000") is not recognized. 
    Range("b2") = Format(Range("a2"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000")
    s1 = Format(Range("a2"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000")
    's1 = "2018-09-03 01:24:33.000"

    'Since you format a2 cell as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000" you can get data as text
    Range("b2") = Range("a2").Text
    s2 = Range("a2").Text
    's2= "2018-09-03 01:24:33.240"
End Sub
```

Sheet Data

[image]

Local Window

[image]